# Retrieve data from external API and display in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Rather than querying a local database I would like to use an external API to retrieve the data to display in the django admin. For simplicities sake I have a model, and plan to retrieve a list of names from the API:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField()
    last_name = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

As it is not managed it therefore does not create the person table. What is the order of functions I must override in ModelAdmin to

1. Perform the API call instead of the database lookup
2. Output the data to a default table in the admin (with first name and last name)
3. Disable functions such as to add (as this will just be a lookup table)
4. Use the django admin search to query the external api - ie. perform a new request and display the new data.